# nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2020-04-20] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]]

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I want to send this request
http://localhost:8080/{url}?start=2020-04-20&end=2020-04-24&status=success&status=failed

In Transaction model

```
private java.sql.Timestamp addedOn;
```

I am trying to create a dynamic query for multiple filters following this blog:
https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-specifications

Specs.java file toPredicate method

```
if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.GREATER_THAN)) {
                predicates.add(builder.greaterThan(
                        root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString()));
} else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.LESS_THAN)) {
                predicates.add(builder.lessThan(
                        root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString()));
}
```

Here is my Controller code

```
Timestamp start = new Timestamp(dateFormat.parse(request.getParameter("start")).getTime());
Timestamp end = new Timestamp(dateFormat.parse(request.getParameter("end")).getTime());
Specs txnSpecs = new Specs();
txnSpecs.add(new SearchCriteria("addedon", start, SearchOperation.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL));
txnSpecs.add(new SearchCriteria("addedon", end, SearchOperation.LESS_THAN_EQUAL));
txnSpecs.add(new SearchCriteria("status", Arrays.asList(request_params.get("status")), SearchOperation.IN));
List<Transaction> txnList = transactionRepository.findAll(txnSpecs);
return txnList;
```

But when I make request I get:

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2020-04-20] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]]
```

Do I need to convert the Date value before I send it as param for the SQL query? Or I need to use other types of Date?

Comment: Can you add you `Transaction` entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to convert the `Date` value before I send it as param for the SQL query?

No, the opposite is true, you must keep it a `Date` but you convert it to a String by calling `criteria.getValue().toString()`.

Comment: When I don't use toString() method.Showing Error :
Cannot resolve method 'greaterThanOrEqualTo(javax.persistance.criteria.Path<Y>, java.lang.Object)'

Comment: I guess you need to cast `criteria.getValue()` to `Date` in order to satisfy the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your dateFormat are correct to pattern of your value: yyyy-MM-dd :

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: Yes my dateformat is correct. But still error is coming